# Map of Ancient Rome

Tags: geography, geographics

I managed to generate a map of the Italic Peninsula with the borders corresponding to 250BC. Is there a way I can shade the area of the Roman empire of the time?

```
redDot = Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}];
blueDot = Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}];

Rome = Entity["City", {"Rome", "Lazio", "Italy"}];
LakeTrasimeno = Entity["Lake", "LakeTrasimeno::946n7"];

GeoGraphics[{
  {GeoMarker[Rome, redDot, "Scale" -> Scaled[0.02]], Black, 
   Text[Style["Rome", Bold], Rome, {-1.5, 0}]},
  {GeoMarker[LakeTrasimeno, blueDot, "Scale" -> Scaled[0.02]], Black, 
   Text[Style["Trasimeno", Bold], LakeTrasimeno, {-1.2, 0}]}},
 GeoBackground -> Dated["CountryBorders", -250],
 GeoRange -> Quantity[1000, "Kilometers"]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found a way of doing it. I must say, I'm speechless about the versatility of Mathematica. Watching this YouTube video was key: [Historical Information in Wolfram|Alpha and the Wolfram Language.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VfoXH4atHlM)

```
redDot = Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}];
blueDot = Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}];

Rome = Entity["City", {"Rome", "Lazio", "Italy"}];
LakeTrasimeno = Entity["Lake", "LakeTrasimeno::946n7"];

GeoGraphics[{{Polygon[
    Dated[Entity["HistoricalCountry", "RomanRepublic"], 
     Entity["MilitaryConflict", "SecondPunicWar"]["StartDate"]]]},
  {GeoMarker[Rome, redDot, "Scale" -> Scaled[0.02]], Black, 
   Text[Style["Rome", Bold], Rome, {-1.5, 0}]},
  {GeoMarker[LakeTrasimeno, blueDot, "Scale" -> Scaled[0.02]], Black, 
   Text[Style["Trasimeno", Bold], LakeTrasimeno, {-1.2, 0}]}
  },
 GeoBackground -> {"CountryBorders", 
   Entity["MilitaryConflict", "SecondPunicWar"]["StartDate"]},
 GeoRange -> Quantity[1000, "Kilometers"]]
```

[image]

**Note**: I used the natural language input feature a lot, but it doesn't show in the code above. For example, I would type `^=` and write Second Punic War and get `Entity["MilitaryConflict", "SecondPunicWar"]`. I wish I knew a way to see what are the attributes of Entities like these. It took me a while to figure out how to extract the start date...

#### Answer to the original question

Here's the map of the Roman Republic in 250BC.

```
redDot = Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}];
blueDot = Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}];

Rome = Entity["City", {"Rome", "Lazio", "Italy"}];
LakeTrasimeno = Entity["Lake", "LakeTrasimeno::946n7"];

GeoGraphics[{{Polygon[
    Dated[Entity["HistoricalCountry", "RomanRepublic"], 
     DateObject[{-250}]]]},
  {GeoMarker[Rome, redDot, "Scale" -> Scaled[0.02]], Black, 
   Text[Style["Rome", Bold], Rome, {-1.5, 0}]},
  {GeoMarker[LakeTrasimeno, blueDot, "Scale" -> Scaled[0.02]], Black, 
   Text[Style["Trasimeno", Bold], LakeTrasimeno, {-1.2, 0}]}
  },
 GeoBackground -> {"CountryBorders", DateObject[{-250}]},
 GeoRange -> Quantity[1000, "Kilometers"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Neat, +1. But how does it correspond to the border right above Trasimeno in the plot in the question?

Comment: @corey979 I added the answer to the original question.

Comment: Cool. Geography is not my thing, but I think I'll play with it a bit. And I guess you can safely accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
redDot = Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}];
blueDot = Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}];
Rome = Entity["City", {"Rome", "Lazio", "Italy"}];
LakeTrasimeno = Entity["Lake", "LakeTrasimeno::946n7"];
GeoGraphics[{Polygon[
   Entity["HistoricalCountry", "RomanEmpire"]], {GeoMarker[Rome, 
    redDot, "Scale" -> Scaled[0.02]], Black, 
   Text[Style["Rome", Bold], Rome, {-1.5, 0}]}, {GeoMarker[
    LakeTrasimeno, blueDot, "Scale" -> Scaled[0.02]], Black, 
   Text[Style["Trasimeno", Bold], LakeTrasimeno, {-1.2, 0}]}}, 
 GeoBackground -> Dated["CountryBorders", -250], 
 GeoRange -> Quantity[1000, "Kilometers"]]
```

[image]

Comment: `Entity["HistoricalCountry", "RomanEmpire"]["StartDate"]` yields `DateObject[{-27, 1, 16}, "Day", "Gregorian", 2.]` (and an `"EndDate"` of `395`), so this does not match the borders at `-250`. I haven't found a match among `Select[Entity["HistoricalCountry"]["Name"], 
 StringContainsQ[#, "Roman"] &]` either.

Comment: Looks like there is only one `"RomanEmpire"` in the database, corresponding to the period of maximum expansion, most likely...