# The Text in GeoMarker

Tags: text, geographics

In continuation the topics [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192478/placing-markers-on-geographic-map) and [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192944/the-specific-geomarker-from-dataset): I had the map "EKB" and I needed to mark some objects. Just for example:

```
AES=
```

[image: aes]

```
TECgas=
```

[image: tecgas]

```
DataSetEkb = Dataset[{
    <|"Names of Objects" -> "Beloyarskaya AES", "Power, MVt" -> 1485, 
     "Coordinates" -> {56.842034, 61.319775}, "Legend" -> AES |>,
    <|"Names of Objects" -> "Tumenskaya TEC-1", "Power, MVt" -> 681.7,
      "Coordinates" -> {57.147139, 65.606861}, "Legend" -> TECgas |>,
    <|"Names of Objects" -> "Tumenskaya TEC-2", "Power, MVt" -> 755, 
     "Coordinates" -> {57.086667, 65.626944}, "Legend" -> TECgas |>}];
```

Thanks to [Sjoerd C. de Vries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/57/sjoerd-c-de-vries) and [Carl Lange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/57593/carl-lange) I have:

```
ekbs = GeoGraphics[{GeoMarker[##, "Scale" -> Scaled[0.025]] & @@@ 
    Values@Normal@DataSetEkb[All, {"Coordinates", "Legend"}], 
   GeoMarker[#1, 
      Style[#2, Bold, Black, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
       FontSize -> 14], "Alignment" -> Top, "Scale" -> Scaled@.2] & @@@
     Values@Normal@
      DataSetEkb[All, {"Coordinates", "Names of Objects"}]}, 
  GeoBackground -> GeoStyling[{"Image", EKB}], 
  GeoRange -> Transpose@{LowerLeftCorner, UpperRightCorner}, 
  ImageSize -> Full]
```

It gives nice way to mark the objects and add the text corresponding the object:

[image: ekb1]

But what if the number of objects is large? In this case, I guess, it is more appropriate to realise something which would allow to add the text correctly ("seamlessly" and without "text overlay").

I mean, what can be done in order **to avoid** the "overlaying" like that:

[image: ekbwrong]

Based on the answers from [here1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147597/add-text-to-geomarker), [here2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171132/map-of-ancient-rome) and [here3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146899/inserting-county-names-on-a-map/146908#146908) I tried to make the GeoMaker for each object separately but something is wrong:

```
ekbes=GeoGraphics[
{GeoMarker[##,"Scale"\[Rule]Scaled[0.025]]&@@@Values@Normal@\
DataSetEkb[All,{"Coordinates","Legend"}],
GeoMarker[Normal@DataSetEkb[[1,3]],Text[Style[Normal@DataSetEkb[[1,1]]\
,Bold,Black],Normal@DataSetEkb[[1,3]],{-1.5,0}]],
GeoMarker[Normal@DataSetEkb[[2,3]],Text[Style[Normal@DataSetEkb[[2,1]]\
,Bold,Black],Normal@DataSetEkb[[2,3]],{-1.5,0}]],
GeoMarker[Normal@DataSetEkb[[3,3]],Text[Style[Normal@DataSetEkb[[3,1]]\
,Bold,Black],Normal@DataSetEkb[[3,3]],{-1.5,0}]]},
GeoBackground\[Rule]GeoStyling[{"Image",EKB}],
GeoRange\[Rule]Transpose@{LowerLeftCorner,UpperRightCorner},
ImageSize\[Rule]Full]
```

Comment: you can use `Text[Style[Normal@DataSetEkb[[1, 1]], Bold, Black], 
 GeoPosition@Normal@DataSetEkb[[1, 3]], {-1.5, 0}]` instead of `GeoMarker[Normal@DataSetEkb[[1, 3]], 
 Text[Style[Normal@DataSetEkb[[1, 1]], Bold, Black], 
  Normal@DataSetEkb[[1, 3]], {-1.5, 0}]]`?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `ListPlot` and `Callout` with `Show` and `GeoGridPosition` to enable automatic label positioning with reduced overlapping.

As of version 11.3 `Callout` is not a graphics primitive so it cannot be directly used in `Epilog`.  However, you can still use `Show` to display multiple graphics together.

The next issue is that `GeoGraphics` is plotted by its `GeoProjection` transformation of lat/long coordinates into Cartesian coordinates; not its lat/long coordinates. Therefore, for `ListPlot` to match its plot to `GeoGraphics` the lat/long coordinates need to be transformed by the `GeoProjection`. `GeoGridPosition` does this transformation.

With `DataSetEkb`, `AES`, and `TECgas` as in the OP, and `LowerLeftCorner` and `UpperRightCorner` as in the posts linked in the OP. Then

```
LowerLeftCorner = {FromDMS["55\[Degree]44'59.75''N"], 
   FromDMS["55\[Degree]46'24.20''E"]};
UpperRightCorner = {FromDMS["58\[Degree]36'01.89''N"], 
   FromDMS["66\[Degree]08'20.36''E"]};

Show[
 GeoGraphics[
  {GeoMarker[##, "Scale" -> Scaled[0.025]] & @@@ 
    Values@Normal@DataSetEkb[All, {"Coordinates", "Legend"}]},
  GeoRange -> Transpose@{LowerLeftCorner, UpperRightCorner},
  GeoProjection -> "Mercator",
  ImageSize -> 800],
 DataSetEkb[
  ListPlot[#,
    PlotStyle -> Transparent,
    Axes -> None,
    PlotRange -> 
     Transpose[
      First@GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition@#, 
          "Mercator"] & /@ {LowerLeftCorner, UpperRightCorner}]] &,
  Callout[
    First@GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition@#["Coordinates"], "Mercator"], 
    Style[#["Names of Objects"], Bold, Black, 
     FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 14, 
     Background -> LightBlue]
    ] &]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The only extra bit is that `ListPlot` must have its `PlotRange` explicitly set to the `GeoProjection` transformed `GeoRange` of `GeoGraphics`.  I think this is because `Show` gets its option values from the graphics it contains and since `GeoGraphics` does not have a `PlotRange` option then it gets it from `ListPlot`. Therefore, to see the entire map `ListPlot` needs to covering the same range of coordinates as `GeoGraphics`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for detailed clarification! It is really helpful for me